# Object Slicing, Is it advantage?

Tags: oop, slice

Object slicing is some thing that object looses some of its attributes or functions when a child class is assigned to base class. 
Some thing like

```
Class A{

}
Class B extends A{

}

Class SomeClass{
A a = new A();
B b = new B();

// Some where if might happen like this */
a = b; (Object slicing happens)

}
```

Do we say Object slicing is any beneficial in any ways?
If yes, can any one please tell me how object slicing be a helpful in development and where it might be helpful?

Comment: C++? The code is not C++, so it is impossible to figure out whether any slicing takes place here from the C++ point of view.

Comment: I am pretty sure that Java does not perform Object slicing, so perhaps that tag should be removed from this question.

Comment: Check the following link
http://www.theserverside.com/tt/articles/article.tss?l=ObjectSlices

Comment: That article presents an interesting way to simulate slicing in Java.  It also presents some situations where you might want to use the technique.  But I believe that what the article is calling slicing is very different from the normal meaning of object slicing as described at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing. In my experience object slicing is something to be wary of.  Sometimes you want it, sometimes you don't, but usually you don't.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In C++, you should think of an object slice as a *conversion* from the derived type to the base type[*]. A brand new object is created, which is "inspired by a true story".

Sometimes this is something that you would want to do, but the result is not in any sense the same object as the original. When object slicing goes wrong is when people aren't paying attention, and think it is the same object or a copy of it.

It's normally not beneficial. In fact it's normally done accidentally when someone passes by value when they meant to pass by reference.

It's quite hard to come up with an example of when slicing is definitively the right thing to do, because it's quite hard (especially in C++) to come up with an example where a non-abstract base class is definitively the right thing to do. This is an important design point, and not one to pass over lightly - if you find yourself slicing an object, either deliberately or accidentally, quite likely your object hierarchy is wrong to start with. Either the base class shouldn't be used as a base class, or else it should have at least one pure virtual function and hence not be sliceable or passable by value.

So, any example I gave where an object is converted to an object of its base class, would rightly provoke the objection, "hang on a minute, what are you doing inheriting from a concrete class in the first place?". If slicing is accidental then it's probably a bug, and if it's deliberate then it's probably "code smell".

But the answer might be "yes, OK, this *shouldn't* really be how things are structured, but given that they *are* structured that way, I need to convert from the derived class to the base class, and that by definition is a slice". In that spirit, here's an example:

```
struct Soldier {
    string name;
    string rank;
    string serialNumber;
};

struct ActiveSoldier : Soldier {
    string currentUnit;
    ActiveSoldier *commandingOfficer; // the design errors multiply!
    int yearsService;
};

template <typename InputIterator>
void takePrisoners(InputIterator first, InputIterator last) {
    while (first != last) {
        Soldier s(*first);
        // do some stuff with name, rank and serialNumber
       ++first;
    }
}
```

Now, the requirement of the `takePrisoners` function template is that its parameter be an iterator for a type convertible to Soldier. It doesn't have to be a derived class, and we don't directly access the members "name", etc, so `takePrisoners` has tried to offer the easiest possible interface to implement given the restrictions (a) should work with Soldier, and (b) should be possible to write other types that it also works with.

ActiveSoldier is one such other type. For reasons best known only to the author of that class, it has opted to publicly inherit from Soldier rather than providing an overloaded conversion operator. We can argue whether that's ever a good idea, but let's suppose we're stuck with it. Because it's a derived class, it is convertible to Soldier. That conversion is called a slice. Hence, if we call `takePrisoners` passing in the `begin()` and `end()` iterators for a vector of ActiveSoldiers, then we will slice them.

You could probably come up with similar examples for an OutputIterator, where the recipient only cares about the base class part of the objects being delivered, and so allows them to be sliced as they're written to the iterator.

The reason it's "code smell" is that we should consider (a) rewriting ActiveSoldier, and (b) changing Soldier so that it can be accessed using functions instead of member access, so that we can abstract that set of functions as an interface that other types can implement independently, so that `takePrisoners` doesn't have to convert to Soldier. Either of those would remove the need for a slice, and would have potential benefits for the ease with which our code can be extended in future.

[*] because it is one. The last two lines below are doing the same thing:

```
struct A {
    int value;
    A(int v) : value(v) {}
};

struct B : A {
    int quantity;
    B(int v, int q) : A(v), quantity(q) {}
};

int main() {
    int i = 12;  // an integer
    B b(12, 3);  // an instance of B
    A a1 = b;    // (1) convert B to A, also known as "slicing"
    A a2 = i;    // (2) convert int to A, not known as "slicing"
}
```

The only difference is that (1) calls A's copy constructor (that the compiler provides even though the code doesn't), whereas (2) calls A's int constructor.

As someone else said, Java doesn't do object slicing. If the code you provide were turned into Java, then no kind of object slicing would happen. Java variables are references, not objects, so the postcondition of `a = b` is just that the variable "a" refers to the same object as the variable "b" - changes via one reference can be seen via the other reference, and so on. They just refer to it by a different type, which is part of polymorphism. A typical analogy for this is that I might think of a person as "my brother"[**], and someone else might think of the same person as "my vicar". Same object, different interface.

You can get the Java-like effect in C++ using pointers or references:

```
B b(24,7);
A *a3 = &b; // No slicing - a3 is a pointer to the object b
A &a4 = b;  // No slicing - a4 is a reference to (pseudonym for) the object b
```

[**] In point of fact, my brother is not a vicar.

Comment: To my mind, the question of whether it should be possible to pass an instance of `A` to code expecting an instance of `B` should be orthogonal to the question of whether it should be possible to pass a reference to `A` to code expecting a reference to `B`.  Even if one were limited to a framework like .NET which didn't have copy constructors, there are many situations where byte-copying a storage location of one structure type to a storage location of another would yield a legitimate instance of the latter type; I wish the Framework had a way of expressing that, especially for...

Comment: ...structures like `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` whose sole purpose is to encapsulate a fixed set of independent values.

Comment: @supercat: so in effect, you're asking for `reinterpret_cast`? I'm pretty sure that for any low-level feature not included in a high-level framework, there will be rare cases where you wish you had it. And as a consequence, for any circumstance in .NET where the only way to do what you want is some C or C++ code to directly inspect bytes, you'll wish you didn't have to bother with the extra source file etc.

Comment: The .NET languages inherently support implicit "reinterpret cast" semantics on assignments of reference-type values to super-type storage locations.  I would like to see a means by which a generic structure `Foo<>` could specify that a `Foo<T>` should be reinterpret-castable to a `Foo<U>` if and only if every field of a `Foo<T>` would support a representation-preserving assignment to the corresponding fields of a `Field<U>`.  The fact that boxed structures are mutable might make things difficult (an `IEnumerable<Foo<Cat>>` would derive from an `IEnumerable<Foo<Animal>>`, but...

Comment: ...a boxed `Foo<Cat>` would not derive from a boxed `Foo<Animal>`), but such facilities would make it possible to use lightweight structures rather than class objects for things like read-only collection wrappers while maintaining support for generic type variance, in addition to allowing things like key-value-pair collections to expose their contents for covariant enumeration.