# Calling a free function instead of a method if it doesn't exist

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Suppose you have a family of type-unrelated classes implementing a common concept by means of a given method returning a value:

```
class A { public: int val() const { ... } };
class B { public: int val() const { ... } };
```

suppose you need a generic free function taking a `T` returning a conventional value for whatever type NOT implementing the `val` method or calling the `val` method for ALL the types that has one:

```
template<class T> int val_of(const T& t) { return 0; }
template<class T> int val_of(const T& t) { return t.val(); }
```

Consider that A and B are just samples: you don't know how many types will ever exist implementing `val`, and how many types will exist not implementing it (hence explicit specialization won't scale).

Is there a simple way, based on the C++ standards, to come to a way to statically select the `val_of` version?

I was thinking to a `std::conditional` or `std::enable_if`, but I didn't find a simple way to express the condition.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is the `state` method? What is `value_of`? What does your second sentence mean?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: sorry, just a misnaming: see the edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a somewhat longer comment... Your question has been answered. But I recently had a similar problem. Say you want to write a method to print strings to `cout`: Use member function `write(std::cout)`, if not available use free function `to_string()`, if not available fallback to `operator<<`. You can use expression SFINAE as in the answer and a little class hierarchy to disambiguate the overloads:

```
struct S3 {};
struct S2 : S3 {};
struct S1 : S2 {};

template <class T>
auto print(S1, T const& t) -> decltype(t.write(std::cout)) {
    t.write(std::cout);
}

template <class T>
auto print(S2, T const& t) -> decltype(std::cout << to_string(t)) {
    std::cout << to_string(t);
}

template <class T>
void print(S3, T const& t) {
    std::cout << t;
}

template <class T>
void print(T const& t) {
    print(S1(), t);
}
```

Comment: Wow... interesting... that's something to really investigate on!

Comment: Great trick. If you're interested, you could generalise it and write an answer for this question: [Is object slicing ever useful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416164/is-object-slicing-ever-useful)

Comment: It's not my trick... :( IIRC, I learned this from `std::advance`. I have just added this as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 16):

You can use return-type SFINAE:

```
template<typename T>
auto val_of(const T& t) -> decltype(std::declval<T>().val())
{
    return t.val();
}

int val_of(...)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But these are two different functions, I think the OP wants a single function

Comment: @Paranaix: it does not matter, until only one of them can exist for a given T but ...

Comment: ... I understand the second to exist when the first fails to instantiate, but when it succeed, both can exist. How does the first be preferred?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Now, but as I wrote my comment he had one function called `val_of` and one called `value_of`

Comment: Ah... got it! The key is in the `...`: it will accept anything and is not preferred in instantiation to the `T` specific, if it can exist.

Comment: [Be careful with elipsis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083844/passing-non-pod-type-to-variadic-function-is-undefined-behavior), though.

Comment: I'm surprised the non-template is not preferred, despite the varargs

Comment: @jrok: [Easy to workaround](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ca04b5230929695)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Me too, [but it seems to work fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cfb09ca0f3d7cfd2)

Comment: @MooingDuck: I think it has something to do with an implicit conversion sequence in the ellipsis expansion (whereas no conversion is required for the arguments in the function template case)

Answer (score 3):

Use this type trait class to determine whether a type has got `val` member function.

```
template<typename U>
struct has_val {
    typedef char yes;
    typedef struct { char c[2]; } no;

    template<typename X>
    static constexpr auto test(int) -> decltype( std::declval<X>().val(), yes() );

    template<typename X>
    static constexpr no test(...);

    static constexpr bool value = sizeof(test<U>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
};
```

You can use it as a condition to `enable_if`.

Comment: Is there a way (probably only with the help of compiler macros) to generalise this to a `has_member_function<int(void),val>` (i.e. `has_member_function<FunctionType,MemberName>` or something similar)?

Comment: @elemakil You can do that with plain old macros only, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

The currently highest voted answer invokes undefined behavior in some cases, so I will give an alternative answer.

We start with some boilerplate machinery:

```
template<typename T> struct type_sink { typedef void type; }
template<typename T> using TypeSink = typename type_sink<T>::type;
```

Then a `has_val` traits class:

```
template<typename T, typename=void>
struct has_val : std::false_type;
template<typename T>
struct has_val<T, TypeSink< decltype(std::declval<T>().val()) > > : std::true_type;
```

We can then use tag dispatching to solve your problem:

```
template<typename T>
int val_of_internal( T const& t, std::true_type /* has_val */ ) {
  return t.val();
}
template<typename T>
int val_of_internal( T const& t, std::false_type /* has_val */ ) {
  return 0;
}
template<typename T>
int val_of( T const& t ) {
  return val_of_internal( t, has_val<T const>() );
}
```

If you find writing `has_val` tiresome and prefer macros, here is a set of macros that write the `has_val` for you:

```
#define EXPRESSION_IS_VALID_FOR_TYPE_T_TRAIT( TRAIT_NAME, ... ) \
template<typename T, typename=void> \
struct TRAIT_NAME : std::false_type {}; \
template<typename T> \
struct TRAIT_NAME< T, TypeSink< decltype( __VA_ARGS__ ) > >: std::true_type {}

#define HAS_NULLARY_METHOD_TRAIT(TRAIT_NAME, METHOD_NAME) \
EXPRESSION_IS_VALID_FOR_TYPE_T_TRAIT( TRAIT_NAME, std::declval<T>().METHOD_NAME() )
```

Now we can write this:

```
HAS_NULLARY_METHOD_TRAIT( has_val, val );
```

but I do not know if it is worth it.